# GLMs vs Time Series analyses

Tags: regression, time-series, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models

apologies for the dumb question but I’m a bit confused on using GLMs versus Time Series techniques.

Say I am interested in determining whether or not a particular year has a higher mean than a baseline year. In my mind (assuming linearity) I’m thinking I could just build a linear regression with a response, $Y$, and a dummy-coded year variable, $X$. However, after doing an (albeit limited) literature review, this is frowned upon, and Time Series analyses are instead recommended.

I just cannot seem to find out why. Are there theoretical advantages to using these methods instead?

Comment: This is the closest related post IMO: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/128854/generalized-linear-models-vs-timseries-models-for-forecasting#:~:text=1)%20GLMs%20are%20rather%20to,)%2C...)%20)%3B. But I’m even more confused lol

Comment: Please provide more details. Is this a two-sample comparison, comparing a baseline sample with some other sample, e.g. like a before-after comparison? In that case, temporal autocorrelation isn't an issue because each of the individual samples are not time series.

Comment: @stweb Not really. It's one sample that just happens to have a time-related variable.

Comment: We still need details on the dataset: response, predictors etc.